# Git: Give access to the master without access to the commit history

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone, git-config, git-rewrite-history

We have our own Git server and want from now to involve external parties in the development of one of our library.

We'd like to have only one repo, keep the commit history private and enable both internal team and external team to work on the same repo.

In Git, how to give access to the current "master" of this library for external parties without access to the commit history (previous versions) which may contain some sensitive data?

Comment: I added details to be more specific. I don't feel the answers to this exiting question address exactly my point.